# Eclipse Java not building due to "active git repository"

Tags: java, eclipse, build, processing

I've got the following error in a java project in Eclipse:

```
The project was not built due to "Folder contains an active Git repository.
The folder cannot be moved, renamed or deleted until the team provider is disconnected.". Fix the problem, then try refreshing this project and building it since it may be inconsistent
```

Any ideas?

It's a Processing.org project and it started after I added a .jar external library file to the build path.

Update:
I've tried committing the git controlled work but that doesn't help.

Update 2:
I've tried pushing up the work to github, deleting the original folder and git repo, deleting all the metadata for the projects and then cloning it all and adding it to Eclipse again but again with no success, error comes back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had the same problem. Click right on project properties, Team -> Disconnect. The error is related to a git issue, related to resources that have been modified. Just disconnect from the git repository, and then connect again (Team->Share project), the error will disappear.

Comment: I can't recreate this at the moment but thank you very much for the answer.  I will make your's as correct (as it clearly "sounds" better than my "solution").

Answer (score 1):

Solved.  I just created a new processing project and then copied and pasted everything from the current project into the new processing folder structure (including just copying and pasting my .git folder), before finally re-adding the .jar to the build path.  Odd.

Answer (score 1):

I disconnected, but still had same issue. So, closed Eclipse went to the folder and deleted files manually. Then it worked fine.